# How to switch classes with JS by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to be able to select only one answer, by Id!

So I started created this js function :

```
function switchclass() {

    let elements = document.getElementsById('A');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 

    {                         
        elements[i].className = 'selected';

        let unselectedelements = document.getElementById('B','C','D')
        
        {
            unselectedelements.className = 'notselected';
        }
     
        {
    }

}
```

[image: Visual]

It still don't work and I don't know what to do then :/ Thanks for any fix!

Comment: This `document.getElementsById`, does this really exist? Can you elaborate what you really want to achieve. and afaik `document.getElementById` only accepts a single parameter

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns **one** element. You can't pass a list of IDs and expect a list of elements. You could iterate over an array of IDs and repeat the logic for each element. `let elements = document.getElementsById('A');` and `elements.length` doesn't make sense. An ID has to be unique. You can't have multiple elements with same ID.

Comment: The brackets don't match. There are 4 opening brackets and 3 closing brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementByID` returns one element matching the `id` attribute.
In this use case, you should be using `class` that is common across all the list items.
On click of the element, remove the `selected` class from all the elements and apply it on the `clicked` element.

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

list.forEach(elem => {
  elem.onclick = function() {
    list.forEach(el => {
      el.classList.remove('selected');
    });
    elem.classList.add('selected');
  }
})
```

```css
.list {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">A</div>
<div class="list">B</div>
<div class="list">C</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

First of all **document.getElementById(id)** can only take one id as a parameter. After that you have to make conditions as per your preference.